# AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding vs AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding with 256 key size performance java

Tags: java, encryption, aes, pkcs#7, pkcs#5

I am currently using `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding` for encrypting files in Java with **256 bytes** key size, but while searching I found on stackexchange [PKCS#5-PKCS#7 Padding](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9043/what-is-the-difference-between-pkcs5-padding-and-pkcs7-padding) and  it is mentioned,

> PKCS#5 padding is a subset of PKCS#7 padding for 8 byte block sizes

So I want to know

1. Will the performance of `AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding` will be better then `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding` for the above configuration?
2. How can we configure the block size in Java as it is mentioned

   > PKCS#7 padding would work for any block size from 1 to 255 bytes.

My sample code is,

```
SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();
IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(rnd.generateSeed(16));

KeyGenerator generator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
generator.init(256);
SecretKey k = generator.generateKey();

Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, k, iv);
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The block size is a property of the used cipher algorithm. For AES it is always 16 bytes.

So strictly speaking, PKCS5Padding cannot be used with AES since it is defined only for a block size of 8 bytes. I assume, AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding is interpreted as AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding internally.

The only difference between these padding schemes is that PKCS7Padding has the block size as a parameter, while for PKCS5Padding it is fixed at 8 bytes. When the Block size is 8 bytes they do exactly the same.

Comment: will it make any difference if I use `AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding` instead of `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding`

Comment: @dbw I don't think so. But to be sure, check the documentation.

Comment: but I don't think so that `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding` is interpreted as `AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding` as if I read [Cipher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) it is mentioned `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding (128)` so this must be having some mechanism defined

Comment: @dbw Interestingly, the standard names document talks only about `PKCS5Padding`. Seems to be a historical mistake since this was correct in `DES` times. In fact the two padding algorithms are identical, the only difference is that PKCS7 has the block length as a parameter while for PKCS5 it is fixed at 8 bytes.

Comment: PKCS5Padding is interpreted as a synonym for PKCS7Padding in the cipher specification. It is simply a historical artifact, and rather than change it Sun decided to simply pretend the PKCS5Padding means the same as PKCS7Padding when applied to block ciphers with a blocksize greater than 8 bytes.

Comment: @Henry any help on a similar [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27921093/rewrite-php-rijndael-algorithm-to-java-android)?