# Which ibm provider support PKCS7Padding

Tags: java, cryptography, jce, pkcs#7

Ibm java has this providers:

```
security.provider.1=com.ibm.crypto.pkcs11impl.provider.IBMPKCS11Impl
security.provider.2=com.ibm.crypto.provider.IBMJCE
security.provider.3=com.ibm.jsse2.IBMJSSEProvider2
security.provider.4=com.ibm.security.jgss.IBMJGSSProvider
security.provider.5=com.ibm.security.cert.IBMCertPath
security.provider.6=com.ibm.security.cmskeystore.CMSProvider
security.provider.7=com.ibm.security.jgss.mech.spnego.IBMSPNEGO
security.provider.8=com.ibm.security.sasl.IBMSASL
security.provider.9=com.ibm.xml.crypto.IBMXMLCryptoProvider
security.provider.10=com.ibm.xml.enc.IBMXMLEncProvider
security.provider.11=org.apache.harmony.security.provider.PolicyProvider
```

due to performance (using ibm provider on aix system is very fast) I cant use bouncy-castle provider to encryption:

```
Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding", providerBC)
```

Is there some ibm provider which can replace bc ?

Comment: Just remove the explicit `providerBC` reference when calling `getInstance` and you will get the cipher from the preferred provider.

Comment: then I got exception: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding         Caused by: javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException: Padding: PKCS7Padding not implemented
 at com.ibm.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineSetPadding(Unknown Source)

Comment: Use "PKCS5Padding" instead. Check http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9043/what-is-the-difference-between-pkcs5-padding-and-pkcs7-padding and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20770072/aes-cbc-pkcs5padding-vs-aes-cbc-pkcs7padding-with-256-key-size-performance-java for more information.

Comment: I cant. It is request of customer

Comment: You obviously did not read the information from the links hudi. Please do so.

Comment: yes I read it. But as I said I cant use PKCS5Padding. Why do you think I didnt read it ? Can you be more concrete ?

Comment: Read it again. PKCS#7 and PKCS#5 define the *same* padding.

Comment: but PKCS7 != PKCS5 and I must use PKCS7 !!!. It is requirement which I cant change so please stop recommenced me PKCS5

Comment: The fact is that PKCS#5 padding is only defined for 64-bit block ciphers. AES is a 128-bit block cipher. It's not possible to use PKCS#5 padding together with AES. When you tell JCE to use PKCS#5, it's actually using PKCS#7.

Comment: then why Cipher throws exception "No such algorithm: AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding" when it is the same ?

Comment: That's a great mystery only the original authors of JCE can answer. Perhaps the API was designed before PKCS#7 was published, or perhaps there were only 64-bit block ciphers in use back then; I don't know.