# Rijndael differences between C# and Java

Tags: java, c#, encryption, cryptography, rijndael

I need to write Java code for encrypting a string using AES (Rijndael).
There is an already working C# code that does this same encryption for the same purpose.
The C# code:

```
RijndaelManaged rijndaelCipher = new RijndaelManaged();
rijndaelCipher.KeySize = 256;
rijndaelCipher.BlockSize = 256;
rijndaelCipher.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
rijndaelCipher.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
byte[] pwdBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password); // password is 32 bytes long
byte[] keyBytes = new byte[32];
System.Array.Copy(pwdBytes, keyBytes, 32);
rijndaelCipher.Key = keyBytes;
rijndaelCipher.IV = keyBytes;
ICryptoTransform transform = rijndaelCipher.CreateEncryptor();
```

The Java code I came up with:

```
byte[] sessionKey = SENDER_KEY.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
byte[] iv = SENDER_KEY.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8) ;
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(sessionKey, "AES");

cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
byte[] cipheredText = cipher.doFinal(stringedXmlForSending.getBytes());
```

When I execute the Java code I get the exception: 
java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Wrong IV length: must be 16 bytes long

Is it true that I cannot write in Java Rijndael encryption which is using 32 bytes keys?
Another difference is that padding in the C# is PKCS7 while in Java there is PKCS5. Will it still work?

Comment: Your question about padding is answered in this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20770072/aes-cbc-pkcs5padding-vs-aes-cbc-pkcs7padding-with-256-key-size-performance-java

Comment: Rijndael with 256-bit blocks is non-standard.

Comment: Can you replace the C# code by something good? It has several flaws. 1) uses a fixed IV 2) the IV is the key 3) no authentication => padding oracle 4) uses a password directly as a key instead of applying a KDF

Comment: Wish I could, but I am accessing an external service which defined things this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic Java Cryptographic Extensions only provide AES implementations which is compatible with Rijndael at 128-bit block size. You should use 128-bit `BlockSize` so that you are compatible with most implementations which implement AES. If you do then the padding is no problem, since [PKCS#5 is the same as PKCS#7 padding in AES](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9043/what-is-the-difference-between-pkcs5-padding-and-pkcs7-padding).

It's important to note that AES is standardized which Rijndael isn't.

Comment: BouncyCastle does seem to provide a Rijndael implementation with variable blocksize, but I only see ECB mode.

Comment: Bouncy Castle uses separate wrapper classes for modes.  Try the CBCBlockCipher class.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled significantly to get this working due to the padding issue. By theory PKCS#5 from java should match PKCS#7 padding from .Net . When I looked deeper into the issue I found that there is an issue with Base64  encoder. Java has different library to encode byte into base64. By default java uses Base64 from `java.util` and it gives padding issue. When I used the different library to achieve this purpose I could get the desired library.

```
org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64String (byte[] encryptedtext)
```