# AES/CFB/PKCS5Padding behaving differently on different Android versions

Tags: android, encryption

I have this encrypting function:

```
String Encrypt(String text, byte[] keyBytes) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB/PKCS5Padding");
    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA".getBytes("UTF-8"));
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);

    byte[] results = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    return Base64.encodeToString(results, Base64.URL_SAFE);
}
```

On most Android devices, it works properly. However, on some old devices (Note 3, LG G2, with Android 4.4) it does not encrypt as it should.

Here's the comparison between two devices. Note3 encryption is wrong and Nexus 6 is OK.

```
Note 3
---------
String to encrypt: Hello, world
Encryption key: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
Encryption result bytes: [108, -63, -66, 117, 62, -78, -108, 22, 12, -128, 119, 22]
Encryption result Base64: bMG-dT6ylBYMgHcW

Nexus 6
---------
String to encrypt: Hello, world
Encryption key: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
Encryption result bytes: [108, -63, -66, 117, 62, -78, -108, 22, 12, -128, 119, 22, 89, -73, -23, 114]
Encryption result Base64: bMG-dT6ylBYMgHcWWbfpcg==
```

Is this a known bug? Anything I can do to fix the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [CFB mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Feedback_.28CFB.29) is a streaming mode which means that it doesn't need padding. So it seems the older version simply disregards your request for PKCS#7 padding (same as PKCS#5 padding).

You have two options:

- Change `Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB/PKCS5Padding")` to `Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB/NoPadding")` so that all versions produce the shortened output.
- If you really need that padding, you can use `Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB/NoPadding")` and manually add the padding before encryption and remove it after decryption. All the [padding bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7) have a value which denotes how many padding bytes there are.

Of course, if you have already a version out there, you really should not change anything, because that would only to errors for the users which use the "misbehaving" devices.

Answer (score 0):

Saw a previous post here:[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20770072/aes-cbc-pkcs5padding-vs-aes-cbc-pkcs7padding-with-256-key-size-performance-java)

And Immediately started wondering about your buffer size and how you're converting.

Both the Note3 and Nexus6 show identical results in the Base64 string for 16 characters, but the 'result bytes' for the Note3 doesn't contain that many bytes!

Can you verify that the byte arrays are the same length, and that the Note3 is actually truncating the missing 4 bytes?  Alternately, create both at a fixed length of 16 and check after the encrypt.