# AES decryption works with Solaris box SunJCE but does not work in AIX box with IBMJCE

Tags: java, encryption, aes, aix

We have recently migrated our infrastructure from Solaris(Oracle/Sun Java) to AIX(IBM Java).

Our clients will upload an encrypted file using the algorithm(AES) and key shared by us,once the encrypted files are placed in our server, an batch routine will decrypt using the same key. This was working well till migration but post migration, the AES decryption functionality does not work.

Earlier we used

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "SunJCE");
```

Post migration, we have changed it as

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
```

When batch is executing, we get exception as below

> javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length (with padding) not multiple of 16 bytes
>           at com.ibm.crypto.provider.AESCipher.a(Unknown Source)
>           at com.ibm.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(Unknown Source)
>           at com.ibm.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(Unknown Source)
>           at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Unknown Source)

The code used for decryption

```
private byte[] decrypt(byte[] data, String corporateId, String algorithm)
        throws Exception {
    String path = corporateId + ".key";

    byte[] key = (byte[]) null;
    try {
        key = returnbyte(path);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    this.logger.info("Provider Info " + cipher.getProvider().getInfo());
    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[16];

    int len = key.length;
    if (len > keyBytes.length) {
        len = keyBytes.length;
    }
    System.arraycopy(key, 0, keyBytes, 0, len);
    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");

    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(keyBytes);
    cipher.init(2, keySpec, ivSpec);
    BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();

    byte[] results = decoder.decodeBuffer(hexStringFromBytes(data));

    byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(results);

    return ciphertext;
}
```

**hexStringFromBytes Method:**

```
public static String hexStringFromBytes(byte[] ba) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < ba.length; i++) {
        if ((i > 0) && ((i & 0x1F) == 0)) {
            sb.append("\n");
        } else if ((i > 0) && ((i & 0x3) == 0)) {
            sb.append("");
        }
        sb.append(hexChars[((0xF0 & ba[i]) >> 4)]);
        sb.append(hexChars[(0xF & ba[i])]);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Not sure about the cause of problem, `cipher.doFinal(results);` throws error.

The class loader also shows that IBMJCE provider being used. Struck with this issue for 3 days. Any direction or guidance to resolve issue is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the input an exact multiple go the block size (16-bytes for AES)? Debug and find out and it it isn't why.

Comment: you take your `byte[]` data, convert it to a hex string, then base64 decode that? That makes no sense at all.

Comment: Note that the OP is a "Technical Architect".

Answer (score 1):

The issue is probably with your padding. As it says " Input length (with padding) not multiple of 16 bytes". As I found in the previous questions, the  is not suitable for AES, cause AES block size is 16, not 8, You can find it below:

[AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding vs AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding with 256 key size performance java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20770072/aes-cbc-pkcs5padding-vs-aes-cbc-pkcs7padding-with-256-key-size-performance-java)

So You must try to use another padding algorithm for it to work.

Comment: It is best tp use an implementation that does PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding by just selecting an option, most do.

Comment: In Java's case PKCS5Padding actually does PKCS#7 padding, so that's not the issue here.